# Symfony/Doctrine not Updating TableName if switched between Querys

Tags: php, symfony, pdo, doctrine

Im Having an Issue with Symfony / Doctrine

Im using multiple tables (**table_entity_1**, **table_entity_2**) for 1 entity and for some reason the `$cm->setPrimaryTable(array('name' => $tableName));` 
doesnt switch the table for `$query=$em->createQuery('...')`

I know that `$cm->setPrimaryTable(array('name' => $tableName));` is called with the right table name

also `dump($em->getClassMetadata('ENTITY')->getTableName());` shows the correct table

yet if i do 2 querys the 2nd query uses the wrong table it uses the same as the first one

here is my Code:

```
public function getAlertDataForReporting($deviceId, $refreshTimestamp)
{
    $tableName = $deviceId . "_alert";

    $em = $this->getEntityManager('s1data');
    $cm = $em->getClassMetadata('S1CoreBundle:S1DeviceDataAlert');
    $cm->setPrimaryTable(array('name' => $tableName));
    $cm->setTableName($tableName);


    dump($em->getClassMetadata('S1CoreBundle:S1DeviceDataAlert')->getTableName());

    $query=$em->createQuery('
        SELECT
        a.acknowledges,
        a.alertId,
        a.errorType,
        a.timestamp,
        a.component,
        a.sensorCounterkey,
        a.alertData,
        a.errorCode,
        a.bus,
        a.address
        FROM S1CoreBundle:S1DeviceDataAlert a
        WHERE a.errorType != 100
        AND a.errorReportedByEmail IS NULL
        AND a.statusType > 20
        AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(a.timestamp) < :refreshTimestamp
        ORDER BY a.timestamp DESC'
    )->setParameter('refreshTimestamp', $refreshTimestamp);



    dump($query->getSQL());
    //dump($query->getParameters());

    $alertData = $query->getResult();

    //dump($alertData);


    return $alertData;
}
```

and here is the Resulting Output:

**"103_alert"**

"`SELECT t0_.acknowledges AS acknowledges_0, t0_.alert_id AS alert_id_1, t0_.error_type AS error_type_2, t0_.timestamp AS timestamp_3, t0_.component AS component_4, t0_.sensor_counterkey AS sensor_counterkey_5, t0_.alert_data AS alert_data_6, t0_.error_code AS error_code_7, t0_.bus AS bus_8, t0_.address AS address_9 FROM **103_alert** t0_ WHERE t0_.error_type <> 100 AND t0_.errorreportedbyemail IS NULL AND t0_.status_type > 20 AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t0_.timestamp) < ? ORDER BY t0_.timestamp DESC`"

**"160_alert"**

"`SELECT t0_.acknowledges AS acknowledges_0, t0_.alert_id AS alert_id_1, t0_.error_type AS error_type_2, t0_.timestamp AS timestamp_3, t0_.component AS component_4, t0_.sensor_counterkey AS sensor_counterkey_5, t0_.alert_data AS alert_data_6, t0_.error_code AS error_code_7, t0_.bus AS bus_8, t0_.address AS address_9 FROM **103_alert** t0_ WHERE t0_.error_type <> 100 AND t0_.errorreportedbyemail IS NULL AND t0_.status_type > 20 AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t0_.timestamp) < ? ORDER BY t0_.timestamp DESC`"

**"408_alert"**

"`SELECT t0_.acknowledges AS acknowledges_0, t0_.alert_id AS alert_id_1, t0_.error_type AS error_type_2, t0_.timestamp AS timestamp_3, t0_.component AS component_4, t0_.sensor_counterkey AS sensor_counterkey_5, t0_.alert_data AS alert_data_6, t0_.error_code AS error_code_7, t0_.bus AS bus_8, t0_.address AS address_9 FROM **103_alert** t0_ WHERE t0_.error_type <> 100 AND t0_.errorreportedbyemail IS NULL AND t0_.status_type > 20 AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t0_.timestamp) < ? ORDER BY t0_.timestamp DESC`"

Note The FROM 103_alerts in EVERY Query

So my issue is that eventho im switching the tablename for the Enitity, the DML still uses the table of the first query in every query

Note that the code black is called from a Service and is within a Custom Repository